# How to use syb mkM

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-generics, syb

I just discovered power of syb library and trying to find its limits.

I've got `everywhere` working:

```
> :set -XDeriveDataTypeable
> :set -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
> import Data.Generics
> newtype MyInt = MyInt Int deriving (Show, Eq, Num, Ord, Data)
> incMyInt (MyInt i) = MyInt $ 1 + i
> printMyInt (MyInt i) = putStrLn $ "MyInt = " ++ show i
> :t mkT incMyInt
mkT incMyInt :: Typeable a => a -> a

> :t mkM printMyInt

<interactive>:1:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘()’ with ‘MyInt’
      Expected type: () -> IO ()
        Actual type: MyInt -> IO ()
```

mkT and mkM look similar and I don't see the reason why mkM is not working for printMyInt

```
> :t mkM
mkM :: (Monad m, Typeable a, Typeable b) => (b -> m b) -> a -> m a
> :t mkT
mkT :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (b -> b) -> a -> a
```

even `pure`

```
:t mkM pure

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Could not deduce (Typeable b0) arising from a use of ‘mkM’
      from the context: (Monad m, Typeable a)
        bound by the inferred type of
                   it :: (Monad m, Typeable a) => a -> m a
        at <interactive>:1:1
```

ghc 8.10.7 and syb 0.7.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printMyInt` has type `MyInt -> IO ()`.

`mkM` expects an argument of type `b -> m b`.

There is a mismatch because `MyInt` is not `()`.

You can write

```
mkM (\x -> printMyInt x >> pure x)
```

---

`mkM pure` is ambiguous. `mkM :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (b -> m b) -> a -> m a` has two type parameters, `a` and `b`, and `b` is undetermined in `mkM pure`. It would not be a problem if `b` were not constrained, but here there is a `Typeable b` constraint that cannot be solved without fixing `b`.